# Ansible import/include variable definition from one of the group_vars to another

Tags: include, ansible

I need to import all variables defined in `/environments/prod/group_vars/test1` to `./environments/prod/group_vars/test2`.

---

Suppose the content of `test1` is as follows:

```
datacenter: ashburn
```

I need the same to be on `test2`.

Comment: group_vars were created with a purpose in mind: to correspond to host groups. There are plenty of ways to assign variables in Ansible without abusing the common sense.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for common variables required by a particular environment we can create "group_vars/all" file and for host_group related variables we can use "group_vars/test1" file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new inventory group 'tests_common_vars' that has 'test1' and 'test2' as children:

```
[tests_common_vars:children]
test[1:2]
```

and put all the common variables in 'group_vars/tests_common_vars'